# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<?> to ArrayList<String> in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

I'm deploying my first tomcat 7 web application to my production server and I'm having troubles...

The web app works perfectly on my development machine with local installation of tomcat 7 within Eclicpse Luna.
But when I try to run it on the production server (Ubuntu 12.04 + Tomcat 7 + openjdk-7-jre-headless), the login.jsp page gives me a lot of compile errors:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /header.jsp
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<?> to ArrayList<String>
7: <head>
8:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
9:  <% 
10:     ArrayList<String> whiteList = new ArrayList<>(
11:             Arrays.asList("login.jsp"));
12: 
13:     String pg = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("/")+1);


An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /header.jsp
Cannot instantiate the type ArrayList<?>
7: <head>
8:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
9:  <% 
10:     ArrayList<String> whiteList = new ArrayList<>(
11:             Arrays.asList("login.jsp"));
12: 
13:     String pg = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("/")+1);


An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /header.jsp
Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token
7: <head>
8:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
9:  <% 
10:     ArrayList<String> whiteList = new ArrayList<>(
11:             Arrays.asList("login.jsp"));
12: 
13:     String pg = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("/")+1);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I guess I'm missing something on my production machine or in configuration files...

Comment: ArrayList<String> whiteList = new ArrayList<String>?

Comment: well it might be but why does the same compile in my local tomcat and not on Ubuntu tomcat?

Comment: yes... that was the issue (shame on me)... still wondering why it is compiling on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by replacing

```
ArrayList<String> whiteList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("login.jsp"));
```

with

```
ArrayList<String> whiteList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("login.jsp"));
```

Regarding why it runs locally but not in 'Live', maybe you are using a different versions of jar (e.g. servlet-api.jar)?